# JavaScript regex matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some variable

```
var jdbcurl="jdbc:oracle:thin:%2F%2Finnova:1521%3BServiceName%3Dorcl%3BMaxPooledStatements%3D20%3BCatalogOptions%3D0%3BBatchPerformanceWorkaround%3Dtrue"

alert(jdbcurl.match(/:[\d]+/));    //gives me :1521
```

How can I get `jdbc:oracle:thin`, `innova`, `1521` & `orcl` out of `jdbcurl` var?

**Update**

You can experiment [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KLPD3/) (if needed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var jdbcurl="jdbc:oracle:thin:%2F%2Finnova:1521%3BServiceName%3Dorcl%3BMaxPooledStatements%3D20%3BCatalogOptions%3D0%3BBatchPerformanceWorkaround%3Dtrue"
var myregex = /([a-z:]+):%2F%2F([a-z]+):(\d+)%3BServiceName%3D([a-z]+)%3BMaxPooledStatements%3D20%3BCatalogOptions%3D0%3BBatchPerformanceWorkaround%3Dtrue/
var matches = myregex.exec(jdbcurl);
// jdbc:oracle:thin is in matches[1], innova is in matches[2], 1521 is in matches[3], and orcl is in matches[4]
```

Answer (score 5):

you could also try this for better url readability during regexp maintenance if you have to parse several urls:

```
var jdburl = unescape("jdbc:oracle:thin:%2F%2Finnova:1521%3BServiceName%3Dorcl%3BMaxPooledStatements%3D20%3BCatalogOptions%3D0%3BBatchPerformanceWorkaround%3Dtrue");

var myRegExp = new Regexp('([a-z:]+)://(\\w+):(\\d+);ServiceName=(\\w+);');

var matches = myRegExp.exec(jdburl);
```

Comment: I think this is a nicer solution than mine.  Why do you have double backslashes for \\w and \\d ?

Comment: It's a string, not a regexp literal, so you need the extra backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `jdbcurl.split(/(%..)/)` would be a start - and then you could check the elements on whether to keep them or split them even further.

Answer (score 0):

Use decodeURIComponent() first, then split on semicolons. Don't make it hard on yourself!